# How to retrieve value from database on check box click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Hi i have three check box where i want that which one check box i select regarding that check box value should retrieve from database

Here is my check box

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="X-Ray" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:120px;"><label>X-Ray</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="Ecg" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:20px;"><label>ECG</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="Blood Test" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:20px;"><label>Blood Test</label>
```

**mysql query**

```
SELECT  SUM(price) from test where test='x-ray' or test='' or test='bloodtest'
```

how can i get my desired output? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why i can't see the server side script?

Comment: @OP : Do u even care to check answers given by people ??? Isn,t this for YOU ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get a hold on the specific `input` checkbox using the jquery selector `:checked`. So something like this in your javascript should get you started :

```
 $( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
   var sel = $( "input:checked" ).val(); 
       //Here you can just make a simple ajax request to a php script passing the 
       //specific checkbox value and let that script perform the mysql query.
       $.post( "test.php", { test: sel })
        .done(function( data ) {
         alert( "Completed");
        });
});
```

Your `test.php` script could look something like this:

```
<?php
   $test = $_POST["test"]; 

   //Replace with your sql database credentials
   $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db"); 

  // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(price) from test where test='".$test."'");
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is a barebone starting template of how you could proceed with your problem. Ofcourse, the specific use case could vary. For instance you could make a `get` request instead of a `post` request and make your php script interact and fetch data differently.

I just gave you an example of how the workflow would look like in simple jquery and php. So you just get the value of input checkbox and pass on the value to a script that interacts with the database and fetches the specific `SUM`. You should probably read some documentation on [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [PHP Mysql](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) to get a better hang of this. Hope it helps.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone explains why the answer was downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

I think that the best solution to this is to output *all* the prices as a JavaScript variable somewhere on the page, Let's alter the HTML a little bit.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox-update" name="test" value="X-Ray"><label>X-Ray</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox-update" name="test" value="Ecg"><label>ECG</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox-update" name="test" value="Blood Test"><label>Blood Test</label>
```

Now, the prices. Use PDO to itterate through results and construct a JSON-formatted variable:

```
<script>
var prices = {"X-ray": 3900, "ECG": 2000, "Blood Test": 1200};
</script>
```

Then use JavaScript to update the price field, I'm using jQuery for this.

```
$('.chkbox-update').click(function() {
    var total;
    $.each($('.chkbox-update'), function(k,v) {
        total += prices[$(this).val()];
    });
    $('#result').text('The total price is '+total);
});
```

**Make Sure** that the key for the `prices` variable matches the `value` of the `<input>`